# Display login and signup menus separately (grouped) using Lift

Tags: scala, authentication, registration

I have the following menu entries in my boot.scala to display a "Home", "About", and user menus from MetaMegaProtoUser:

```
val homeLink = new Link("index" :: Nil, false)
val homeMenu = Menu(Loc("homeHome", homeLink, "Home"))
val aboutLink = new Link("about" :: "index" :: Nil, false)
val aboutMenu = Menu(Loc("aboutHome", aboutLink, "About"))
val menus = homeMenu :: aboutMenu :: User.menus
LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(menus: _*))
```

In my default.html I have the following to render the menu:

```
<lift:Menu.builder li_item:class="active" linkToSelf="true"></lift:Menu>
```

I want to have the "Home" and "About" menus grouped in one location and the User.menus in a separate location in my page (e.g. upper right showing as "Login | Sign up".

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `Menu.group` snippet, which allows you to render menu items for a specific `LocGroup`.  There is an excellent chapter on the webpage [Exploring Lift](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-7.html) in section 7.5.2.

> The LocGroup allows you to categorize your menu items... A menu item may be associated with one or more groups.  Simply add a LocGroup param with string arguments for the group names.

This means you can do something like this,

```
val entries = (
    (Menu("Login") / "login" >> LocGroup("main")) ::
    (Menu("Logout") / "logout" >> LocGroup("user")) ::
    (Menu("Profile") / "profile" >> LocGroup("user", "main")) ::
    (Menu("Home") / "index" >> LocGroup("main")) :: Nil
)
```

After adding `entries` to your `Boot.scala` through a

```
LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(entries: _*))
```

You can render only the menu items for the `LocGroup("user")` with,

```
<div id="userMenu">
    <div class="lift:Menu.group?group=user;a:class=userLink"></div>
</div>
```

Notice in the `Menu.group` call you identify the group by passing in the parameter `group=user` and can pass in stylizing parameters too, such as the `a:class=userLink`.

You are then free to style the #userMenu how you want, put it wherever etc. and go for as many groups as your heart desires!